# Big Query how to show second and third highest score

Tags: google-bigquery

recently im doing a assignment and i face some tricky question that ask us to only show second and third highest score and i have tried many times still can't get the way to solve this problem

This is my code:

```sql
SELECT 
Dealer_ID as ID, count(No__of_Cars_Won) as NoOfCarsWon
From potent-symbol-314008.Assessment.Dealer
group by Dealer_ID
order by count(No__of_Cars_Won) desc
limit 3
```

can anyone send help?

Answer (score 0):

> only show second and third highest score

Consider below query

```sql
 SELECT Dealer_ID as ID, count(No__of_Cars_Won) as NoOfCarsWon
   From potent-symbol-314008.Assessment.Dealer
  group by Dealer_ID
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NoOfCarsWon DESC) IN (2, 3)
```

###### Reference

- [DENSE_RANK](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#dense_rank)() returns the ordinal (1-based) rank of each row within the ordered partition

> All peer rows receive the same rank value, and the subsequent rank value is incremented by one.

- [QUALIFY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) clause filters the results of window functions.